# How can i get image dimensions after upload with jQuery File Upload?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-file-upload

When i try to upload a file via jQuery File Upload i am taking below response.

[image: It returns "false"]

Is it posible to add image dimensions to this result like `width: 300px` and `height: 400px`? I try to edit `UploadHandler.php` for that need but i can't success. There is a function called `set_additional_file_properties` in `UploadHandler.php`. I tried to add a custom variable to the function but it fails because i think this function called before the file upload process. It even could not find the file to get dimensions. I don't know why probably i am looking to wrong side of the document.

```
protected function set_additional_file_properties($file) {
    $file->dimensions = file_exists($file->url);
    $file->deleteUrl = $this->options['script_url']
        .$this->get_query_separator($this->options['script_url'])
        .$this->get_singular_param_name()
        .'='.rawurlencode($file->name);
    $file->deleteType = $this->options['delete_type'];
    if ($file->deleteType !== 'DELETE') {
        $file->deleteUrl .= '&_method=DELETE';
    }
    if ($this->options['access_control_allow_credentials']) {
        $file->deleteWithCredentials = true;
    }
}
```

### Solution

```
protected function set_additional_file_properties($file) {
    $a = getimagesize(realpath(dirname($file->url))."/".$file->name);
    $width = $a[0];
    $height = $a[1];
    if ($a) {
        $file->width = $width;
        $file->height = $height;
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get your problem (you want to add width and height information to the image on the server side) then this should help:

http://php.net/manual/function.getimagesize.php

> Returns an array with up to 7 elements. Not all image types will include the channels and bits elements.
>   Index 0 and 1 contains respectively the width and the height of the image.

=> getimagesize($file)

Comment: "If accessing the filename image is impossible getimagesize() will generate an error of level E_WARNING. On read error, getimagesize() will generate an error of level E_NOTICE."

So have a look at the error. I assume the file does not exist or you do not have the permissions to gather the information.

Comment: Also I tried `file_exists` and It returns `false` too. Probably i try to get dimensions before the upload done. All i need is the right section in `UploadHandler.php` to add `getimagesize` in it. But i can't find yet.

Comment: Just use the debugger and stop it at the beginning of the set_additional_file_properties function. Then you check on the filesystem if the file actually exists yet. You can transform your relativ url ("../../../files" and so on) to an absolute path by using the realpath function in php: http://php.net/manual/de/function.realpath.php that'll make debugging easier.

Comment: Well, I don't know which IDE you are using and whether it has a debugger, but a simple (but surely not elegant) way of stopping php from executing is to insert "die();" in the next line.

Comment: `exit()` can stop the execution. Beside `realpath` is the trick! I think it will work. I can update the answer with a solution when i am done. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Only need to change `UploadHandler.php` file in `set_additional_file_properties($file)` function for the following:

```
protected function set_additional_file_properties($file) {
    $filesize = getimagesize("files/".$file->name); //'files' folder is default folder to upload
    $width = $filesize[0];
    $height = $filesize[1];
    if ($filesize) {
        $file->width = $width;
        $file->height = $height;
    }
    $file->deleteUrl = $this->options['script_url']
        .$this->get_query_separator($this->options['script_url'])
        .$this->get_singular_param_name()
        .'='.rawurlencode($file->name);
    $file->deleteType = $this->options['delete_type'];
    if ($file->deleteType !== 'DELETE') {
        $file->deleteUrl .= '&_method=DELETE';
    }
    if ($this->options['access_control_allow_credentials']) {
        $file->deleteWithCredentials = true;
    }
}
```

just added these lines:

```
$filesize = getimagesize("files/".$file->name); //'files' folder is default folder to upload
$width = $filesize[0];
$height = $filesize[1];
if ($filesize) {
    $file->width = $width;
    $file->height = $height;
}
```